# Further calculations from calculated fields in libreoffice base

Tags: hsqldb, calculated-columns, radix, libreoffice

Working on LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 / HSQLDB 1.8.0.10

Calculated fields are quite easy.. eg; "Field Name1" + "Field Name2" in a third field = a simple sum.

In my database I ***think*** I need further calculations from calculated fields within the same query.

These two sql statements are in the same query:

- BuyPrice
- S/H Paid
- TaxPaid

"BuyPrice" + "S/H Paid" + "TaxPaid"

When the query runs, this outputs to a field with an alias of **Total Cost**

- SellPrice
- S/H Charged

"SellPrice" + "S/H Charged" - ( "SellPrice" * 0.132 + "S/H Charged" * 0.132 )

This outputs to a field with an alias of **NET**

This is exactly what I need, however I also need a third calculated field for Profit. I cant just enter "**NET**" - "**Total Cost**". If I create another query on top of the first one, I can reference the aliases and it works just fine but I can only get this into two separate "**Table Controls**"

Should this possibly be separate queries??

I simply don't know enough about any of this to get it to work.. any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, you cannot use aliases within queries.  You have to write out the entire calculation

```
"SellPrice" + "S/H Charged" - ( "SellPrice" * 0.132 + "S/H Charged" * 0.132 ) - ("BuyPrice" + "S/H Paid" + "TaxPaid")
```

to alias it to a column PROFIT.  If you write two queries, when the program runs it internally writes out all the code like this.  Two queries adds a bit of overhead calculation for the queries to be combined.  The overhead may be worth it if it makes the queries more maintainable by you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Perfect! It worked like a charm. For you i'm sure this was simple, but for me I was lost. lol  I immediately assumed the only way to do it was to calculate based off of the results from the other calculated fields.